# Is it possible to label port in SSH port forwarding?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

Is it possible to label port and use the label name instead of the port number in SSH port forwarding?

For example, a normal ssh port forwarding would be:

```
ssh -L 5432:localhost:5432 remotepc
ssh -L 8081:localhost:8081 remotepc
```

But is something like below possible?

```
ssh -L postgres:localhost:postgres remotepc
ssh -L my_app_server:localhost:my_app_server remotepc
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `ssh` will accept service names defined in the `/etc/services` table. Your OS already has some entries there (mostly unused), but you can add your own.

(For Windows this is `\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\services`, just like the hosts file.)

Note that the file might *already* contain 5432, under the official IANA name `postgresql`. In that case you can add shorter aliases at the end of the same line:

```
postgresql 5432/tcp postgres psql
```